# margin-right doesn't work on a table

Tags: css, html-table, margin

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9pF5/).

Why CSS for `td.mar` doesn't work? 
**Or:** how to make table keep space from the screen's border on the right side?

**EDIT:** for anyone who might be looking for an answer:
`display: block` and `border-collapse: collapse` were disabling the `margin-right` property

Comment: It does work. Not sure what you are seeing on that side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a `padding-right ?px;` on the table.

**Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/s9pF5/11/**

Comment: I see it works but somehow didn't work for my table. Now I know that it was `display: block` and `border-collapse: collapse` that were disabling the `margin-right` property

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `table` to have a margin to the right, you should apply that margin-right to the `table`, not the `td`.

Answer (score 0):

Your can create one `td` and **write the css** as Like this
**Css**

```
.noBorderwithMargin{border:0;padding:0;margin:0;padding-left:50px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td class="pad-l">item</td>
        <td class="pad-r">item</td>
        <td class="pad-t">item</td>
        <td class="noBorderwithMargin"></td> // add this td 
        <td class="mar">margin</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s9pF5/8/)**

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/s9pF5/10/) is not exactly what I need, there's still no space between the table and right side of the screen's border

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping the table?

HTML:

```
<div class="margin">
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td class="pad-l">item</td>
    <td class="pad-r">item</td>
    <td class="pad-t">item</td>
    <td class="mar">margin</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS (added two styles):

```
table {
    width: 100%
}
div.margin {
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5Hvu/)